# Symfony 2 entity join or doctrine query join

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine, entity

I was wondering if it was possible to configure a entity to automatically load data from another entity.
Ex.

```
/**
 * accountsUsers
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class accountsUsers
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="userid",type="integer")
     */
    public $userid;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="roleid",type="integer")
     */
    public $roleid;
    /**
     * @var string
     * admin,adviser,etc
     * @ORM\Column(name="roleType", type="string", length=255)
     */ 
    public $roleType;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $firstname;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $lastname;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="company", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $company;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $url;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $phone;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone2", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $phone2;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $address;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address2", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $address2;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $city;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $state;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="zip", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $zip;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $email;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $password;
}
```

AND

```
/**
 * accounts
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class accounts
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="partnerid", type="string", length=100)
     */
    public $partnerid;
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="subscribedate", type="date")
     */
    public $subscribedate;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="connectionType", type="string", length=100)
     */
    public $connectionType;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="recordkeeperTpaid", type="string", length=100)
     */
    public $recordkeeperTpaid;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="recordkeeperAdviceProviderCd", type="string", length=100)
     */
    public $recordkeeperAdviceProviderCd;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="recordkeeperUrl", type="string", length=200)
     */
    public $recordkeeperUrl;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="recordkeeperUser", type="string", length=100)
     */
    public $recordkeeperUser;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="recordkeeperPass", type="string", length=100)
     */
    public $recordkeeperPass;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="recordkeeperPortfoliosAvailable", type="smallint")
     */
    public $recordkeeperPortfoliosAvailable;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="recordkeeperRiskBasedFundsAvailable", type="smallint")
     */
    public $recordkeeperRiskBasedFundsAvailable;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="investmentsMinScore", type="integer")
     */
    public $investmentsMinScore;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="investmentsMaxScore", type="integer")
     */
    public $investmentsMaxScore;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ACAon", type="smallint")
     */
    public $ACAon;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="MSTClientID", type="string", length = 100)
     */
    public $MSTClientID;
}
```

Is it possible to set up accountsUsers to automatically load in all the accounts data when accountsUsers is accessed by findby, findbyone, etc.  The relationship is accountsUsers.userid = accounts.id.

If not, how would I do this in a join using doctrine.  I know how to do it using pure raw sql.

> Ex. SELECT * FROM accounts a  LEFT JOIN accountsUsers b  ON a.id =
>   b.userid

Comment: The manual is a good place to start learning about Doctrine 2 relations.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: I looked over the manual it didn't help me at all.

Comment: Nevermind I got it! I had to go through the example very slowly lol.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to load separate entities in one query (i.e. with a JOIN) just by using annotations. You'll have to define a custom query in your repository which instructs *Doctrine*, via *DQL* or `QueryBuilder`, to join with the related entities.

It was a big gotcha for me as well, but using `fetch="EAGER"` in the annotation defining the association doesn't actually use a `JOIN` to retrieve the result - it just issues 2 separate queries to pre-fill the relationship so that its first access does not trigger the lazy loading process.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159333/doctrine2-eager-loading-runs-multiple-queries-instead-of-1) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony developed relations which give you the ability to define a property in entity files and relate it to other entity.
There are two ways.

**First way:**

In your case,
first you have to make a column in users table(for example name it `account`) and relate it to `account.id` column using foreign key's, then in App\Entity\Accounts  you can define a property name `$users` and relate it to App\Entity\Users like code below:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Users", mappedBy="account")
     */
    private $users;
```

and one in `App\Entity\Users`

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Accounts", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $Account;
```

like this whenever you get a object from `App\Entity\Accounts`
a key with the name `users` will return that have the information of all of this account users just the result:

```
    SELECT * FROM accounts a LEFT JOIN accountsUsers b ON a.id = b.userid
```

will give you.

The **second way** is pretty easy just by using make:entity command

```
php bin/console make:entity
```

you can make a new column and make a relation for it, command will ask you about everything step by step and its pretty much so simple working with it that you don't need to read the document but if you need more information this is the link to read about it
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#the-manytoone-onetomany-association